# Image resize in detail view in YII@

Tags: yii2

I am using the below code in detail view page to render image. The image is rendered correctly, but it is not getting resized. what I am doing wrong?

```
[
            'label'=>'photo',
            'value'=>'uploads/' . $model->photo,
            'format' => 'image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100'],
            ],
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dear Pawan, `'format' => 'image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100'],` should be : `'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],`. Not?

Comment: Dear Ali, Thanks. I have tried that also, but it didn't worked, so I was trying this variation. But may be the problem was in Yii2. After updating the composer update now ur suggest code is working fine. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yii\helpers\Html;`

```
[
'label'=>'Image',<br>

'value'=>Html::img(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/media/category/'.$model->image,'width'=>200, 'alt'=>'no image']),<br>
'format'=>'raw'
],
```